# WordPress menu post featured image

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a menu with multiple dropdowns.
I want to show bellow or beside the link of a post or posts in a menu dropdown the featured image. Is it possible?
I've attached an image to this message. 
I don't want to know how to style it or something like that. 
So let's say I have **"Siguranta"**, I want to display the featured image of that post underneath and a "Read more" link under the image. Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I will answer my own question. I finally did it with this code:

```php
  // get featured image
  $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $item->object_id );

  //display featured image
  $item_output .= $thumbnail;
```

I have to mention that I used this code in the walker class.

Answer (score 3):

**Add filter to specific menus**

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'add_filter_to_menus');
function add_filter_to_menus($args) {

    // You can test agasint things like $args['menu'], $args['menu_id'] or $args['theme_location']
    if( $args['theme_location'] == 'header_menu') {
        add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'filter_menu_items' );
    }
}
```

**Filter menu**

```
function filter_menu_items($item)
{

    if ($item->type == 'taxonomy') {

        // For category menu items
        $cat_base = get_option('category_base');
        if (empty($cat_base)) {
            $cat_base = 'category';
        }

        // Get the path to the category (excluding the home and category base parts of the URL)
        $cat_path = str_replace(home_url() . '/' . $cat_base, '', $item->url);

        // Get category and image ID
        $cat      = get_category_by_path($cat_path, true);
        $thumb_id = get_term_meta($cat->term_id, '_term_image_id', true); // I'm using the 'Simple Term Meta' plugin to store an attachment ID as the featured image

    } else {
        // Get post and image ID
        $post_id  = url_to_postid($item->url);
        $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
    }

    if (!empty($thumb_id)) {
        // Make the title just be the featured image.
        $item->title = wp_get_attachment_image($thumb_id, 'poster');
    }

    return $item;
}
```

And then you want to remove the filter that you applied at the beginning, so that the next menu processed doesn't use the same HTML as defined above in *`filter_menu_items()`*.

**Remove filters**

```
 add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','remove_filter_from_menus', 10, 2);
    function remove_filter_from_menus( $nav, $args ) {
        remove_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'filter_menu_items' );
        return $nav;
    }
```

Comment: So, how can I implement that in my menu code? Thanks.

Comment: That does not help me at all. I want to know how to make it, I don't want to buy it.

Comment: i have ubermenu you like it?

Comment: I can't say I don't. thanks for your help, but that's not what I'm looking for. I just wanted a way to add in my worpdress menu with posts the featured image of them, with my own menu.

Comment: I've seen this already on my google search. I don't want to display icons. I want to display the featured image.

Comment: ok try this http://digitalnature.eu/blog/2011/10/27/featured-images-thumbnails-in-menus/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83425/discussion-between-bhavesh-vala-and-user3275665).

Comment: let me to the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83425/discussion-between-bhavesh-vala-and-user3275665

Comment: This is the code I came up with thanks to some help from a Wordpress StackOverflow answer that I can't find anymore (please comment with a link if you find it).

First you need to add the filter to the specific menu (you could add it to all menus if you want - just use the add_filter line by itself).

Comment: That did not worked for me. I tried UberMenu. Can you tell me why UberMenu is not displaying my images?

Comment: active your UberMenu and setting completed after display and go apearance->menu set

Comment: I already done that. And then I clicked on Uber on menu item and from those settings I've gone to "Image", I selected an image I saved and still not working even though the image is saved in admin. But it's not displaying on front end menu.

Comment: Try setting  http://sevenspark.com/tutorials/ubermenu-wordpress-mega-menu-shortcode-grid   `and`  http://sevenspark.com/docs/ubermenu-easy-integration  `and` http://sevenspark.com/tutorials/displaying-username-ubermenu

Comment: Those tutorials are not longer necessary as this functionality is built into UberMenu 3 with Dynamic Posts. So it should work without the functionalities and shortcodes from those tutorials.